# How to move South Pole in cartopy projection?

Tags: python, maps, projection, cartopy

I'm plotting maps of Antarctica about 38 million years ago with cartopy, see this plot made with the code below. The continent, however, was then more to the southeast with respect to present day as you can see by the contours, so therefore I would like the continent to be at the center of my map (i.e., to choose a different location for the South Pole). I think I need another projection, but I don't know which one and how then to use the arguments for that projection.

[image: output]

```
#Defining circle for maps
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
center, radius = [0.5, 0.5], 0.5
verts = np.vstack([np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]).T
circle = mpath.Path(verts*radius + center)

#Plotting
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude = 0, central_latitude = -90))
ax1.set_extent([0, 360, -90, -57], ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.set_boundary(circle, transform = ax1.transAxes)
MI.plot.contourf(ax = ax1, transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap = "Reds", levels = 11, cbar_kwargs = {"label": "monsoonal index [-]"})
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try setting `center,radius=[0.6, 0.4], 0.6`.

Comment: Now it is your move to answer your own question. I will wait to vote it up. It is normal to answer one's own questions.

Comment: I can't wait to see the new plot. ;p

Comment: .... and you can click to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to swatchai: changing the `center, radius` values helped:

```
#Defining circle for maps
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
center, radius = [0.58, 0.44], 0.5
verts = np.vstack([np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]).T
circle = mpath.Path(verts*radius + center)

#Plotting
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude = 0, central_latitude = -90))
ax1.set_extent([0, 360, -90, -57], ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.set_boundary(circle, transform = ax1.transAxes)
MI.plot.contourf(ax = ax1, transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap = "Reds", levels = 11, cbar_kwargs = {"label": "monsoonal index [-]"})
plt.show()
```

This results in the plot:

[image: outputplot]